# How to compare the group operations in homotopy and homology groups?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

Consider the following Lemma from p.173, Chapter IV of Bredon's *Topology and Geometry*:

> If $f$ and $g$ are paths in $X$ such that $f(1)=g(0)$ then the $1$-chain $f*g-f-g$ is a boundary... Note that this lemma implies that one can replace the $1$-simplex $f*g$ by the $1$-chain $f+g$ modulo boundaries.

$*$ is concatenation for $n=1$ in particular and the group operation in $\pi_n(X)$ for all $n \ge 1$ in general.

**Question:** Does the analogous statement for $\pi_n(X)$, $H_n(X)$, $n>1$, hold?

> If $f,g: S^n \to X$, $[f],[g] \in \pi_n(X)$, $n>1$, are such that $f*g$ is defined, then the $n$-chain $f*g -f-g$ is an $n$-boundary. In particular, one can replace the $n$-simplex $f*g$ by the $n$-chain $f+g$ modulo boundaries.

I suppose there is a subtlety I am overlooking, namely how to identify continuous maps $f,g,f*g:S^n \to X$ with continuous maps $\Delta_n\to X$ -- if this subtlety makes the question unanswerable in any meaningful sense please let me know.

A reference will suffice for an answer; please don't forget the page number.

Comment: What does "*" mean in your second highlighted piece of text? Is $X$ supposed to be a topological group here?

Comment: Also: The Hurewicz (sp.?) Theorem, which says that if the homotopy groups less than $n$ are trivial, then $\pi_n$ is isomorphic to $H_n$.

Comment: @JohnHughes * is supposed to be concatenation for $n=1$ in particular and the group operation in $\pi_n(X)$ for all $n \ge 1$ in general.

Comment: If it's the group operation in $\pi_n$, then it should probably be $[f] * [g]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I read all the definitions, but ...

An element $\alpha$ of $\pi_n(X_n, x_0)$ is represented by a map $f$ from $D^n$ to $X$ where $\partial D^n$ is all mapped to $x_0$. Writing $D^n$ as a union of $n$-simplices ($Q = [0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ is the union of the triangles in $Q$ defined by $x \ge y$ and $x \le y$; the analogous cube $Q$ is the union of 6 tetrahedra, defined by all possible orderings of $x,y,z$, etc.), every map such as $f$ gives rise to an $n$-chain $c = W(f)$ with $n!$ simplices, defined by restricting $f$ to each of the simplices that constitute $D^n$. And $c$ is a cycle, because its boundary is (with some work) the restriction of $f$ to $\partial D^n$ combined with a bunch of internal pieces (like the diagonal of the square) that cancel out because of ... careful checking on the signs of permutations that correspond to each of the $n!$ constitutive simplices. Getting this right is a pain in the neck (for me, at least).

If $f$ and $g$ represent two homotopy classes in $\pi_n(X, x_0)$ that can be "starred" (which, as I recall, involves pasting together their domains along an $n-1$-face, and then scaling by a factor of two alone the orthogonal line in the domain), then it's pretty clear that $W(f*g) = W(f) + W(g)$ as chains, where the "=" here means "differ by a boundary".

I guess the conclusion I draw is that $W: \pi_n -> H_n$ is homomorphism.

Ah...I'm right. It's called the [Hurewicz homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurewicz_theorem), and the linked Wikipedia article (or Hatcher's book, I'm sure) will tell you all about it. The Hurewicz *theorem* says that the homomorphism is an isomorphism IF the lower homotopy groups are trivial.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply -- there was a fire in my apartment building and I haven't had internet for a week (still don't-- I'm not at home now). It took me a while to realize why the Hurewicz homomorphism is relevant here, but now I'm embarrassed because it's obvious. Thank you for the well-thought out answer -- this is also the nicest description of the homomorphism I have seen so far, amd makes the idea much more accessible. Thank you again!

Comment: That noise I heard this morning must have been you slapping your forehead! :) Glad to have been of service. (Good luck getting back home, too!)